# DB Alias on Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, synonym

I need to run a migration from my server1 to server2, in both servers have the same DB schema

Server1:
  DB1.dbo... All tables
  DB2.dbo... All tables

Server2:
  DB1.dbo... All tables
  DB2.dbo... All tables

I need connect from server1 to server2, and also until I finished this script, I have to run on Local environment and the DB names are different (like DB1_Local instead of DB1)

I try to create a synonym for "Server1.DB1.dbo" so when I have to join a table of Server1 with other on Server2 I'll run

MySynonymForServer1.MyTable JOIN MySynonymForServer2.MyTable ON ....

But this doesn't work...

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synonyms are for objects. You cannot create a synonym for a schema or a database. However, you can create a synonym fo an object in a different database. so in your case, you have to create a synonym for every object in the database. You could automate that by looping through the objects in `sys.objects`. Just make sure to filter out unwanted object types like constraints.